# RSpec: testing path to route mapping (but not the other way around)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, routes

I need to use the functionality of `params_from`, which was deprecated. Now `route_to` combines behavior of `params_from` and `route_for`. But I do not want to test that the *route* generates the *path*, because it does not and this is intentional (for backward compatability in old emails, I need to "alias" old path to the correct controller/action, but path generated by the new route will be different. I know, confusing ;)

When using `params_from` and `route_to`, I get conflicting results (maybe params_for is broken?):

```
# params_from(:get, 'user/tasks').should == { :controller => 'user', :action => 'tasks' }
No route matches "user/tasks" with {:method=>:get} 

# { :get => 'user/tasks' }.should_not be_routable
Expected 'GET user/tasks' to fail, but it routed to {"action"=>"tasks", "controller"=>"user"} instead
```

The route does exist, I can use the path via UI successfully.

IMO this combination of `params_from` and `route_for` is a bad idea, unless the seperate matches are still supported. But maybe I've missed something obvious ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I was looking for, and found it while hacking the source code:
`assert_recognizes({ :controller => 'user', :action => 'tasks'}, 'user/tasks', {}, nil)`

I will probably wrap it under `params_for` matcher.

Answer (score 0):

What's the value of testing your routeset explicitly?

You should probably get this for free if you write even a minimal functional test for your controllers.